# Problem using transformation constraints to rotate gears

Tags: animation, constraints

So, I'm working on a clock and to help me animating it I am using transformation constraints, but when I put it in the third gear it started reversing the rotation after rotating some degrees, going back and forth.
[image: example]
This is what is happening.

I already used transformation constraints before but I never had this problem.
I tried changing the values, activating Extrapolate, reseting the rotations but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/FSYiDLv2fjw and https://youtu.be/h37WgwkkTFg are the two videos I refer to when doing gears.  O.T. Vinta has several other useful ones as well. In a nutshell you use a hinge Rigid Body Constraint which allows the gear to rotate around the Z axis of the constraint object (an empty).  The gear and the axle are Rigid Bodies; the gear is active, the axle is passive.

Comment: i tried using rigid bodies, but for this clock model its not worth it, too heavy for processing and not accurate. thx anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do these kind of thing is using a combination of armature and ***Animation Nodes***. download this addOn from [here](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases/tag/v2.0).

Do the following:

[image]

1. Add an armatures in the location of each gear and set its rotation
2. Combine all armatures (so you will have a clean armature for all of
   your gears)
3. Create nodes in animation nodes as explained in the gif file
4. Link each gear to the corresponding bone.
5. Done!

Comment: I think its more simple using constrains or drivers, but I'll give it a try. thx.

Comment: in this way you can have all of your gears in a single node tree. it gives you a cleaner access to all of your gears.

Answer (score 0):

First I think that you were wrong with the settings, and also it looks like you need to apply the rotation of the big wheel (don't ask me why, it must have to see with its local axis of course), then it works:

[image]

Comment: well, the thing is that I don't want to apply the rotation. I tried to use 'from Local Space to Local Space but it was not working.

Comment: yes it's hard to understand, maybe there's a bug in this constraint